# how to create multtple image auto silder use amp in html

Tags: javascript, html, slider, amp-html

I am new in the amp. I want an automatic image slider using multiple images in this  photo i have slider but this not automatic slider can any help how to create multiple image slider using amp.
This is the image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use `autoplay` attribute in carousel

The autoplay attribute (type="slides" only) advances the slide to the next slide without user interaction, by default it will advance a slide in 5000 millisecond intervals (5 seconds) and can be overridden by the delay attribute.